# Background image not appearing in webpage in .net

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have put a link to my image but I cant seem to get it to display in my webpage.

I have also tried to put the image in a separate folder but I still couldn't get it to display.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have attached a photo to show my folder structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKK7x.png)

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active"
                 style="background-image: url(./bball.jpg); ">
                <div calss="container">
                    <h1>Example Headline</h1>
                    <p>
                        nionsdof nlsdfn klnsdf nsdklfnklsnfd kln
                        sl;df ;lkfsmdlmsdl;ksm dl;m klms lksfkj sjh
                        skdf jsdkjfn kn kjnsdf kjnsdkn sdfjk nksdf kj
                        s fdkjsdfk jnskdj nskdjnf jknfsdkjnskjdnf ks
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                        Sign up today
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: It looks as though bball.jpg is in the same folder as your source file so remove the ./  (Incidentally you have a spelling error - calss instead of class - on the next line).

Answer (score 0):

remove the styling image line you made:

`style="background-image: url(./bball.jpg);`

In your css file, insert this:

```
carousel-item active.image {
    content:url("bball.jpg");
}
```

or

```
div.carousel-item active{
    background-image:url("bball.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but that didn't work

Comment: Actually, instead, could you replace "background-image: url(./bball.jpg); " with "background-image: url(./Views/Home/bball.jpg); "

Comment: I get the following error when I do that 

GET https://localhost:44367/Views/Home/bball.jpg 404

Comment: Did you remove the './' as suggested above? It seems that your code is index.cshtml and the image are in the same folder.

Comment: Yip tried that, but still no good

Comment: This is what I get when I remove it GET https://localhost:44367/bball.jpg 404

Comment: I tried replicating this with the information provided and a sample image and It worked first go. Something else must be happening on your end.